# How do I access the instagram API with Express JS and Jade?

Tags: node.js, api, express, instagram, mean-stack

I am having some trouble getting information for Instagram's API and the sending it to Jade to be rendered on the front end.

```
app.route("/api")
.get(function(req, res){
    var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1234/media/recent/?client_id=XXXX";

    request(url, function(err, res, data){
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        // does this go here 
        res.render('show', {media : data});
    });
    // or here?
    res.render('show', {media : data});
});
```

I am trying to collect 10 images from this API path and send them to Jade. I am getting a parsed response in my terminal of several entries. I am having a hard time figuring out how to send multiple responses to a Jade file, then having the Jade file loop through them.

I do know that the user ID and client ID in the `url` variable are not correct. If you have any alternate method to using `request()`, I am open to that as well.

Comment: You seem to have the right code in place. There's no "multiple" calls to the Jade. Only one, then the jade gets rendered and sent to browser. You can have Jade iterate inside any array present in your "data" variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I am answering my own question on this one. The rendering has to be inside of the request() function. The issue was in my callbacks. The issue was that I had "res" as a response for my .get and my request() callback. When I changed the "res" in the request() function to "response" I was not getting any issues anymore. Jade file is below as well

```
app.route("/api2")
.get(function(req, res){

    var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1234/media/recent/?client_id=XXXX";

    request(url, function(err, response, body){
        var dataGram = JSON.parse(body);
        res.render('show', dataGram);
    });
});
```

Jade File:

```
each thing in data
   h1 id : #{thing.id}
   img(src="#{thing.images.thumbnail.url}")
   a(href="#{thing.link}" target="_blank") link
   h3 filter : #{thing.filter}
```

Comment: what is request in answer