# Securing API Token, is making it a var in my index.js possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have built a html form to interact with Slack.  Currently my js code looks like this.

```
$("#submitemail").click(function(){
    $.post(
            "https://openpgh.slack.com/services/hooks/incoming-webhook?token=MY_SECRET_TOKEN",
            JSON.stringify({'text':'invite request from: '+$("#email").val(),'username':'Slack Inviter','icon_emoji':':raising_hand:'})
    ).success(function(){
                $("#email").val("");
            });
});
```

if anyone were to just copy this right out of my html file they could just run a console command and change the JSON and bombard my slack group with massive amounts of nonsense until they hit the API call limit.

What I am wondering is if I could store this in my index.js (I am using a node.js template) as a var and then call it in the html.

Any options or advice is greatly appreciated I am very new to this.

My structure is:

```
Slack App
|_node_modules
| |_express
|_public
| |_index.html
| |_node.svg (idk what this does)
|_.gitignore
|_app.json
|_index.js
|_package.json
|_procfile
|_README.md
```

the code for my index.js is just

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
});
```

I can throw in my full html if you want its just a basic modal w/ a button to click to execute the form and pull the email.

Comment: You *could* but it doesn't really solve the problem, because anyone could just pop open the console and view the index.js source. Ideally, you would make the API call on the server side, and then pass the results up to the browser.

Comment: hummm ok I will look into that.  My index.js is what is serving my app from the server so maybe i am wording it wrong

Comment: Still a little stumped as to how to make this occur on the server side got a good tutorial i can dig through?

Comment: Yeah no problem. Would you mind posting your app.js (and possibly directory structure) so I cant take a look? For starters, you'll need [node request](https://github.com/mikeal/request). There a few good examples on that page as well. I'll dig up a couple more examples for you

Comment: [Here's a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577611/http-get-request-in-node-js-express) thats *not* using the request module. And here are a couple that *are* using the request module [Get 3rd party api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224070/get-3rd-party-api-with-express-js-and-jade) and [Making HTTP requests in Node](http://www.sitepoint.com/making-http-requests-in-node-js/)

Comment: Basically, the `request` module I linked to up there will take care of a lot of the boilerplate for you. But it's good to know and there are several ways to do it. Let me know if you have questions, those will at least get you started.

Comment: Thanks man I am pulling them up

Comment: no prob. In a nutshell, you'll have to 1) write a function in your index.js that calls the slack api using the `request` module and stores the response in a variable/JSON object (which is pretty much what you had originally, just need to move it onto the server side). Then 2) You can keep your same on click function, but instead of calling the Slack API, you call your own api, ie http://yourdomain/getSlackData. Does that make more sense? I can try and write out a psuedo-answer

Comment: ya man that makes some sense...but def write a psuedo-answer so i can give ya credit for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: this code is untested

You would basically do something like this:

index.js (commented to explain what i added):

```
var express = require('express');
// install request module
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

// make a new route that you can call from the client side
app.get('/getSlackData', function(req, res) {

  //variable to hold your response from slack
  var slackResponse;

  //make the request to slack
  var slackUrl = "https://openpgh.slack.com/services/hooks/incoming-webhook?token=MY_SECRET_TOKEN""
  request(slackUrl, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      slackReponse = response;
    } else {
      console.log(error);
  });
  return slackResponse;
});

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
});
```

So we added a new route, that is basically an API you can call from the client side, it will return the JSON object that you got from Slack. You can pretty much leave your client side code the same, just change the route you're calling:

```
$("#submitemail").click(function(){
$.post("/getSlackData",
    JSON.stringify({'text':'invite request from:'+$("#email").val(),'username':'Slack Inviter','icon_emoji':':raising_hand:'})
  ).success(function(){
    $("#email").val("");
  });
});
```

I hope I understood your question correctly, this should at least get you pointed in the right direction.